# Cybersource payment response

Tags: java, jsp, payment-gateway

```
    <form id="receipt">
        <%

            HashMap params = new HashMap();
            Enumeration paramsEnum = request.getParameterNames();
                  while (paramsEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
                String paramName = (String) paramsEnum.nextElement();
            String paramValue = request.getParameter(paramName);
                params.put(paramName, paramValue);
                out.print("<span>" + paramName + "</span><input type=\"text\" name=\"" + paramName + "\" size=\"50\" value=\"" + paramValue + "\" readonly=\"true\"/><br/>");
                }
```

I have written this code in response page linked this page in cybersource setting. But its giving null value its not return anything. But I am getting mail with full payment details. How can i get it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a null check before show the all parameters, and you don't need to create a HashMap, Enumaration interface help you to iterate and show the params and values.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Enumeration"%>

<%
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        Enumeration<String> params = request.getParameterNames();
        if (params == null) {
            out.println("Parameters are empty");
            return;
        }
        while (params.hasMoreElements()) {
            String param = params.nextElement();
            String paramValue = request.getParameter(param);
            out.println(param + ": " + paramValue + "</br>");
        }
    %>
```